# How do I take a library from Ubuntu 18.04 and make it an AWS Lambda Layer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, binaryfiles, aws-lambda-layers

I've had a lot of luck with AWS Lambda and layers (specifically, node modules). I'm in a place where I have a [font conversion library](https://github.com/bdusell/webfont-generator) that I'd like to adapt and make available via a serverless request.

At the moment, I don't even know where start. I have a simple build script which you can see below that works fine for when building it for Ubuntu 18.04, but adapting this to a Lambda Layer env goes beyond me.

Would appreciate any guidance or ideas.

```sh
## 1.3.2
cd ~/
mkdir ~/webfont-generator-1.3.2
cd ~/webfont-generator-1.3.2
wget https://github.com/bdusell/webfont-generator/archive/1.3.2.zip
unzip 1.3.2.zip
rm 1.3.2.zip
mv webfont-generator-1.3.2/* .
rm -rf webfont-generator-1.3.2
sudo apt-get install -y default-jdk=2:1.10-63ubuntu1~02
sudo apt-get install -y python=2.7.15~rc1-1
sudo apt-get install -y default-jre=2:1.10-63ubuntu1~02
sudo apt-get install -y ant=1.10.3-1
sudo apt-get install -y fontforge=1:20170731~dfsg-1
sudo apt-get install -y python-fontforge=1:20170731~dfsg-1
sudo apt-get install -y maven=3.5.2-2
sudo /usr/bin/printf '\xfe\xed\xfe\xed\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe2\x68\x6e\x45\xfb\x43\xdf\xa4\xd9\x92\xdd\x41\xce\xb6\xb2\x1c\x63\x30\xd7\x92' | sudo tee /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
sudo ./setup
```

Comment: This is a large library with many external dependencies.  I'd recommend looking at building a Docker for Lambda (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) to contain all of these things.

Comment: Yeh that's what the author suggested as well. I don't have any exp w/ Docker unfort. Is the build process for something like that v involved?

Comment: @onassar a bit late but I would recommend using https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda they have nice docs and Yumda

Comment: Thanks @TomásCot I'll take a look soon :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this via layers. Your Ubuntu dependencies are run at the OS level. With a normal lambda deployment, AWS uses its standard Linux Base image which is not possible to (easily) change.

I have never tried it, but you can build your own OS base image in docker, and then use AWS Elastic Container Registry to store this base image. You can then tell Lambda to use this image instead of the default one.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

Comment: Thanks GWed. I appreciate the guidance. I wondered if it was even possible. Naturally, if it's not possible, it begs the question whether I should be doing it ;) I'll keep searching for what my options are. Creating an image in docker and then using it via AWS ECR and then over to lambda seems a bit over complicated :(